# NLP packages to check similarity between 2 sentences

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, unsupervised-learning

Are there any NLP packages that can help to identify if two words or sentences are related to each other in some way?

Like `helmet` is related to `bike`, `software` is related to `developer`
`I've built a product` is not related to `I'm a boy`

Any idea how can I perform such comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare strings using Levenshtein distance, it will give you a score as an output on how similar the strings are.